# Convert from a list to an array of `SqlParameterSource`. A.K.A. convert a list to an array of maps

Tags: java, arrays, list, stream, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I have a list of entities which I want to relate to another entity using JDBC named template. For that, I am inserting the ID pairs on the join table using a batch update operation, but the problem is that the way I have found to generate an array of `SqlParameterSource` is a little bit clunky. Is there any way of doing this with an stream instead?

```java
// Create an array of the size of the fruit list.
final SqlParameterSource[] fruitParameters = new SqlParameterSource[tree.getFruits().size()];

// Get all the fruits to iterate through.
final List<Fruit> fruits = tree.getFruits();

// Fill the array with the parameter sources.
for (int i = 0; i < fruitIds.length; i++) {
    final var fruit = fruits.get(i);

    final var parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("fruit_id", fruit.getId());
    parameters.addValue("tree_id", tree.getId());

    fruitParameters[i] = parameters;
}
```

I think the problem boils down to converting a list to an array of maps.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 fruits.stream().map(fruit-> {
        var parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("fruit_id", fruit.getId());
        parameters.addValue("tree_id", tree.getId());
        return parameters;
    }).toArray(SqlParameterSource[]::new);
```

if you can create method that take Fruit object and return MapSqlParameterSource would be better from readability point of view and you just call that method inside the map method

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR you welcome and you can check this tutorial by oracle for stream https://dev.java/learn/the-stream-api/ :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll definitely check that link!